# Bracketing when filtering on mutiple fields

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, criteria

A question on brackets when filtering:

```
df.info()

RangeIndex: 4005 entries, 0 to 4004
Data columns (total 41 columns):
currency_str                   4005 non-null object
state                          4005 non-null object

display(
        df[
            df['currency_str'] == 'INR'  
        ])
```

Displays my INR rows correctly.

When I add the second filter I require double brackets around both otherwise I get errors.

```
display(

        df[
            (df['currency_str'] == 'INR')    &  
            (df['state'].str.contains('Done'))
        ])
```

What's going on under the hood here with Pandas? The & is not enough? Is this specifically related to string fields where the criteria is enclosed in ''?

No Brackets

```
display(
        df[
            df['currency_str'] == 'INR'    &  
            df['state'].str.contains('Done')
        ])
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [bool] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

One set of brackets

```
display(
        df[
            (df['currency_str'] == 'INR'    &  
            df['state'].str.contains('Done'))
        ])
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [bool] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

Comment: It should be work can you show us the error code

Comment: Two examples added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should adding `()` for each condition

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'currency_str':['INR','INR','None'],'state':['LOLDone','l','Done']})

df[(df['currency_str'] == 'INR') &(df['state'].str.contains('Done'))]
Out[789]: 
  currency_str    state
0          INR  LOLDone
```

Comment: Yes as I've mentioned above. My question is why is this required and is it specific to string fields?

Comment: @PeterLucas that is require for all not only for string

Comment: @PeterLucas `&` and `|` are bitwise logical operators rather than the python "logical" operators like `and` and `or`